# Javascript, exponentially calls function after nth-recursion

Tags: javascript

I'm just getting started with Javascript and jQuery and have run into a little bit of trouble on my first project. I'm building a simple Blackjack game which works perfectly the first time through.

Once the first hand is over, the game is supposed to reset and play again by calling a recursive playGame() function once a button, #playAgain, is clicked. This works fine, but after playAgain is executed, my hitMe function breaks for the user. It is a systematic code, so both the user and PC are performing the same action, but it is behaving differently for the user and begins to exponentially call the hitMe function based on the number of games played.

Why would this code behave differently in this case based on the user/computer providing the call and how could I go about fixing it?

The code can be found at www.calebdwilliams.com/blackjack

Comment: Please post the most relevant parts of the code here. And welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here inside your playGame function:

```
$("#hit").click(function(){
```

You are wiring up a click function to the #hit element every single time you play the game. Well, the subsequent times through the game javascript is just adding additional click handlers. That hander should be added only once either outside the scope of playGame() or else the previous listeners should be removed with:

```
$("#hit").unbind();
```

Comment: Note, you should still update this question with your code so that the post makes sense. Otherwise this will just get closed.

Comment: How should I post the code? Is there a preferred method or etiquette for the sit? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Caleb, the question is closed so you probably can't update it now, but what you want to do is excerpt the portion of code you think most relevant to your problem. In your case you didn't really know what part was the issue so you could just put your entire blackjackmod.js file in the notes. You indent each line four spaces to tell SO that you are inputting code. The more narrow you focus your code pasting the better chances of a good response. So since you suspected the #hitme click was the problem you might have just pasted the playGame function.

Answer (score 2):

You bind event handlers inside the `playGame` method.

That means that each time you run it it binds an additional handler to the elements you want..

So you need to unbind before binding in that method..

Whenever you do a `.click(...)` do a `unbind('click')` first..

```
$("#stand").unbind('click').click(function(){
```

and

```
$("#hit").unbind('click').click(function(){
```

and

```
$("#playAgain").unbind('click').click(function(){
```

Comment: +1 for putting the unbind inline with the click handler.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the help. I'll familiarize myself with the unbind function.